# PHP OOP Login system stdClass::$id

Tags: php

When I login with the correct information I get the following message:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in /var/www/classes/User.php on line 37
>   Success Login!
>   Line 37 in User.php is following
>   Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

Also after i sign in and update page and go to `/index.php` just to try print out the session, I get nothing.
Following command on index.php page

```
echo Session::get(Config::get('session/session_name'));
```

If i don't sign in and just go to index.php i get the following message
Notice: Undefined index: user in /var/www/classes/Session.php on line 12

**Login.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {

        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array('required' => true),
            'password' => array('required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();
            $login = $user->login(Input::get('username'), Input::get('password'));

            if($login) {
                echo 'Success Login!';
            } else {
                echo 'Login failed';
            }
        } else {
            foreach($validation->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="field">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Logga in">
</form>
```

**Session.php**

```
<?php
class Session {
    public static function exists($name) {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function put($name, $value) {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }

    public static function get($name) {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public static function delete($name) {
        if(self::exists($name)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }

    public static function flash($name, $string = '') {
        if(self::exists($name)) {
            $session = self::get($name);
            self::delete($name);
            return $session;
        } else {
            self::put($name, $string);
        }
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
<?php

class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {
        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('Could not create account');
        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null) {
        $user = $this->find($username);

        if($user) {
            if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }


}
```

**Token.php**

```
<?php

class Token {
    public static function generate() {
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), sha1(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token) {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if(Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
            Session::delete($tokenName);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dump and inspect the contents of `$this->data()` It would appear that it is an object with no `id` property.  `var_dump($this->data())`

Comment: var_dump output this-  object(stdClass)#7 (6) { ["ID"]=> string(2) "16" ["username"]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(128) "SHA512 hash" ["salt"]=> string(40) "salt here" } 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$id in /var/www/classes/User.php on line 38
Success Login!

Comment: Your property is called `ID`, not `id`.  PHP's array keys, variables, and object properties are case sensitive!

Comment: yes your right! Many thanks to you! Didn't check the sql tables.